# Questions about Very Old Pre-ARC Objective-C Code

Tags: ios, objective-c

We have an app with super messy code created by some other development company long time ago. Recently we found out there was a bug inside it. After hours of debugging, we found out that if we comment out one of the release command of one of the ViewController when done using then the code works perfectly. My questions are:

1. Is commenting out the release command can cause significant memory leak?
2. Will the ARC in recent days can handle this issue (still can release the memory without release command)?
3. If I add code as normally writing ARC code, will the old code and new code coexist in the same file?

The code was so old so we don't want to take the risk of converting it to ARC code. If the answer to above question 3 is yes, then it will be much more comfortable for us to change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Randomly removing `release` is the same as randomly subtracting 1 from some variable because you have an off-by-one error and now it "seems to work better." Yes, it can absolutely lead to more problems. Memory management cannot be safely done by simply adding and removing `retain` and `release` until it "seems to work."

My recommendation is to let Xcode convert the code for you to ARC (Edit>Refactor>Convert to Objective-C ARC....) If you had incorrect memory management before, this is not guaranteed to fix it (particularly retain loops), but there are a wide number of mistakes that it will automatically address. Beyond that, you will need to debug the errors in memory management.

If it's not possible to convert this code to ARC, run the static analyzer (Cmd-Shift-B). You should do this anyway, even after converting to ARC. There are a lot of memory problems it can't find, but there are a lot it can.

Comment: +1 for static analyzer. I'm not particularly "good" at memory management but that's saved me on quite a few occasions.

Answer (score 2):

1) it may cause a "significant" memory leak depending on what kind of object will leak, and how many times it is allocated (what if it's in a loop that iterates million times? :-)

2) ARC can be enabled / disabled on a per-file basis. You can't have ARC and NON ARC code in the same file. If you want ARC to handle that situation, you have to convert at least that file

3) as written in the answer 2, no, they can't coexist in the same file.

Last, hiding errors is always a bad practice that can give you a lot of work in the future...I suggest you to add the code that gives you the error, maybe someone can give you an hand to resolve

Comment: For the first answer, it is a customized UIViewController that needs to be dismissed, this UIViewController maybe never get alloced over 10 times each time the user use the app. Will that cause a big leak?

Comment: the answer is always "It depends". The VC itself uses not so much memory, but what if it retains other objects? For example images, buttons, views, ecc? All this objects will leak together with the VC

Answer (score 0):

1. It's impossible to tell without seeing the code. Potentially, yes.
2. Yes — ARC does memory management for you.
3. No. ARC is done on a file level - you can't combine ARC and non-ARC code in the same file, and enabling ARC will cause all calls to `retain`, `release` and `autorelease` compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Yes**, without releasing objects they will most likely "hang out" in memory, inaccessible to your program.
2. The whole reason for using ARC is to handle memory automatically. So, **yes, it will release the memory without using the `release` message**. (In fact, the compiler throws an error when you try to build a file marked for ARC with a `release` directive within.)
3. **Not exactly**. It is possible, but not without some [compiler magic](http://weblog.invasivecode.com/post/45606299813/mixing-arc-and-mrc-source-code-in-the-same-class) available in `clang`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry you have to see this in the hard way.

1. Quite possible. One single view can occupy a lot of memory in pre-ARC ages, and without properly releasing properties, a single line of code can leak a lot of memory, if called many times. I have done this before and was very excited when ARC is introduced, it's just magic. And also, if you want to see the exact result, you will like the leak tool in Instruments.
2. Yes! This is what ARC is made for. There is only one bad news: it requires you to convert the whole file to ARC, which you don't want to do.
3. No. At least not officially supported. There might be some magic, but may or may not break in some future release, and you (definitely) don't want to risk it.

I'm afraid none of the answers above can make you feel better, so you'd better get started to fix that, better in the ARC way.